# Input Button onclick event not firing

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom-events

I'm fairly new to JavaScript and trying to build a simple photoviewer, slideshow application. I probably have errors/wrong practices in code that I don't know about yet. The event on slideshow button fires and I can see the output in the console, however the event on the random slide show button does not fire.

HTML5 snippet

```
<form>
   <div id="controls">
       <input type="button" id="slideshow" value="Slide Show" />
       <input type="button" id="randomSlideshow" value="Random Slide Show" />
   </div>
</form>
<script src="js/PhotoViewer.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS snippet

```
var photosArrayGlobal = new Array();
var photoIndexGlobal = 0;
var displayGlobal;

window.onload = main;

function main() {
  "use strict";
  document.getElementById("slideshow").onclick = getArrayPhotosNames;

  document.getElementById("randomSlideshow").onclick = randomize(photosArrayGlobal);

  displayGlobal = document.getElementById("myImage");

  document.getElementById("nextSlide").onclick = function () {
    displayGlobal.setAttribute("src", photosArrayGlobal[1]); //Test value, image 2
  };
}

function getArrayPhotosNames() {
  var folderName = document.getElementById("photoFolder").value;
  var commonName = document.getElementById("commonName").value;
  var startNum = document.getElementById("startNum").value;
  var endNum = document.getElementById("endNum").value;
  var j = 0;

  if (startNum > endNum) {
    alert("Invalid Numbers");
  }

  var nameArray = new Array();

  for (var i = startNum; i <= endNum; i++) {
    nameArray[j] = folderName + commonName + i + ".jpg";
    j++;
  }

  photosArrayGlobal = nameArray.slice();
   console.log(photosArrayGlobal);

  return nameArray;
}

function randomize(dataArray) {
  var i = dataArray.length;
  var j, tempi, tempj;
  if (i === 0) {
    return false;
  }

  while (--i) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    tempi = dataArray[i];
    tempj = dataArray[j];
    dataArray[i] = tempj;
    dataArray[j] = tempi;
  }
 console.log(dataArray);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `onclick` handler is expecting a function, but you're passing it the value returned from the `randomize()` function (which happens to be `undefined`). Change it to the following:

```
document.getElementById("randomSlideshow").onclick = function() {
    randomize(photosArrayGlobal);
};
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. Is it possible to debug the code and figure out problems like this like you can with Java/Eclipse combination ?

Comment: Yes, there are lots of tools to do this. I personally use Google Chrome and its built-in developer tools to debug pages. (To bring up the tools, right-click and click on "inspect element" or Ctrl+Shift+J and switch to the "Sources" tab.)